# How to save input of text in the text field into a file?

Tags: php

Guys i am a complete noob in PHP, and so i need help with my question. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <input id="name" placeholder="test 123" value="" type="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

I would like the name field to be saved to a text file.

Comment: Use file_put_contents();

Comment: When you search for "PHP write text to file" on Google, what do you find?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the input name first.

```
    <div class="form-group">
<form method="post" action="filename.php">
                      <input id="name" placeholder="test 123" value="" name="name" type="name" class="form-control">
    </form>
                    </div>
```

Send the post data to the php page. And paste this code there

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
file_put_contents("file_name.txt",$name); // Will put the text to file
?>
```

Hope this helps you